# Make Javascript RSA message encryption giving same result

Tags: javascript, rsa, public-key-encryption

Hello I'm using a javascript RSA encryption process and it's working :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
            <head>
            <title></title>
              <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="base64.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="asn1.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="jsbn.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="prng4.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="rng.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="rsa.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="pemconvert.js"></script>
              <script>
                    function loadpubKey(){
                            var pubkey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAPBYvSszUjI5psKM958bHTDb+9NONv3X\nWVIGLR9/Al4j8/mqSDMhwFuu9oEyXl80+Ga2cohEQPpWyxzg3/tfGDUCAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
                            $("#publicKey").html(pubkey);
                        }
                    function RSAEncryptData()
                        {
                            var Message = $("#Message_to_Encrypt").val();
                            var pubkey = pem_import($("#publicKey").val());             
                            $("#RSAMessageEncrypted").html(pubkey.encrypt(Message));
                        }
            </script>
            </head>
        <body onload="loadpubKey();">
        <h1>RSA Encryption/Decryption using library From :https://github.com/tao-software/jsrsa</h1>
        <form>
                <strong>Public key         :</strong> <textarea rows="3" cols="100"  id="publicKey"></textarea><br>
                <strong>Message to RSA encrypt :</strong> <textarea rows="3" cols="100"  id="Message_to_Encrypt"></textarea><br>
                <input type="button" value="RSA Encrypt" onclick="RSAEncryptData();">
                <strong>RSA encrypted Message :</strong> <textarea rows="3" cols="100"  id="RSAMessageEncrypted"></textarea><br>
        </form> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Each time I hit "encrypt" button using the same message to encrypt I get a new different encrypted value. What can I do to make this encryption giving the same encrypted result for the same message used?

Actually what I want to do is to encrypt some phone numbers with a public key using RSA then store them in a table after that I will encrypt any phone number that I'll get through a process with the same public key in RSA and look in the table if there is a match.

With the script above I will never find a match even if I'm encrypting the same phone number more than once that's why I want the result to be the same when encrypting the same phone number. Any idea is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is supposed to be different every time. That is what the pkcs#1 block type 2 padding does, for security purposes. Why do you want it to be the same?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying, Please I need it to give the same result when using the same message to encrypt because I want to be able to make a comparaison later between my encrypted massages (don't worry about this) I heard that it requires a SALT or an RSA 0 padding but I'm confused I don't know how to make it do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

As Greg states in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426186/make-javascript-rsa-message-encryption-giving-same-result#comment20083095_14426186), the randomness in the PKCS #1 padding will cause your encrypted result to vary each time.

Based on your use case, I would suggest you store a hash of the phone number alongside the encrypted data. You can then perform a quick lookup based on the hash. You may wish to salt your phone numbers prior to hashing.

*Bear in mind that hashes are not guaranteed to be unique, so there is a teeny-tiny chance you'll get two hashes that clash.*

Comment: Hi, I just want to know if there is a way to make this PKCS #1 padding not generating a random values used for encryption, and do you think that hashing 2 different RSA encrypted results will give the same hashed values? I don't think so. Thanks.

Comment: The randomness is there for a good reason, don't try to remove it. I'm suggesting you hash the unencrypted phone number, which will always produce the same result.

Comment: "The randomness is there for a good reason, don't try to remove it" hhhh Please I'm posting this question because I need it to give the same result I need to modify it don't you understand and sorry. I can't use hash because it's not reversible and want to decrypt the phone number (after finding a match) using the corresponding private key (I have a process set for that).

Comment: I'm suggesting you store *both* the hash and the encrypted value.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to *sign* a message with your private key and have other *verify* the signature with your public key. The libraries you have linked to provide an RSASign and RSAVerify methods, possibly under the `sign` and `verify` methods of an `RSAKey` instance. I'm not a JS programmer so all I can say is that's what it looks like.

Comment: Hello, actually what I want to do is to encrypt some phone numbers with a public key using RSA then store them  in a table after that I will encrypt any phone number that I'll get through a process with the same public key in RSA and look in the table if there is a match. With the script above I will never find a match even if I'm encrypting the same phone number more than once that's why I want the result to be the same when encrypting the same phone number. I hope I was clear, thanks for any idea that can help.

Comment: @user1789193: you should edit your question to add that information to it.